# KVO on UIViewController childViewControllers array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Using [accessors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178830-BAJEDEFB) seems to be the way to get KVO notifications on collection objects, but this doesn't appear to work on the childViewControllers NSArray property of a UIViewController. I want to be notified when an object is added or removed to this property. So I tried this:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"childViewControllers" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

-(NSUInteger)countOfChildViewControllers
{
    return self.childViewControllers.count;
}
```

But I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, I'm not getting any notifications. Is what I want possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that all modifications of the property have to go through KVO-compliant means.  This has to do with how `UIViewController` is implemented, nothing you can do from outside of that class.  Using the indexed collection accessors is one way that the implementation of `UIViewController` could achieve KVO-compliance, but there are others.  I don't know if that property is KVO-compliant; from what you report, apparently not.  Adding getters or even setters in a category or subclass doesn't help if the underlying implementation doesn't use them.